# How to create select filter on meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have table with users and select with user's last name, when I change select option and choose option like 'black' need to show on table only people with last name 'black'. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the change on the select element by using a 'change' event and save the information in a Session variable:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'change #namePicker': function(event, template) {
        Session.set('name', template.find('#namePicker').value);
      }
});
```

Use {{#each user}} in the HTML to generate a row for each user in your HTML table:

```
<tbody>
   {{#each user}}
     <tr>
        <td>{{firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{lastName}}</td
     </tr>
   {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

And add the corresponding helper to fetch the user's data:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    'user': function(){
        var nameToFind = Session.get('name');
        if(typeof nameToFind !== 'undefined')
        {
            return Meteor.users.find({lastName: nameToFind});
        }
        return;
    }
});
```